# dict comprehension with list as value

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I have a program that prompts the user for three pieces of input:

Student No.
Name
Age

I then populate a list with this info. This currently works fine.

I was wanting to change the list construct to a dictionary that has the Student No. as the key and a list with the Name and Age as values.  I also want the list in case I decide to enlarge the number of inputs in the future.

I was wondering if I could use a dict comprehension but I can't find any examples of using a dict comp being used to create a dict with a list as the value.

The resulting dictionary would look like:

```
st_dict = {101: [Mark, 54],
           102: [Bob, 49]
           }
```

Is it possible, using a dict comp, to create this structure?

Basically I am wanting to do this:

st_dict = {Student_no: [Name, Age] per student entered}

Comment: Have you actually tried to flesh out that last line? Looks ok to me if you finish turning it into actual code.

Comment: Wow.  Totally embarrassed.  I was so worried about not finding examples of what I was trying to do, I never simply tried it.  It works just fine.